# Which Ubuntu version should I use?

Tags: boot, compatibility, system-requirements

I have a 1.5GB RAM PC , with 32bit processor and I run windows 8.1 in it without any problem and it runs normal in Windows 8.1 and I needed a specific version for my PC please don't recommend me Lubuntu or Xubuntu please I need Ubuntu only please specify me with a particular version of Ubuntu only, I don't need Lubuntu or Xubuntu.
Thanks,

Comment: See this link: [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Comment: There are only one 32-bit version of *standard* Ubuntu per release. So there are currently two supported 32-bit releases of Ubuntu: 14.04 LTS (supported until 2019) and 16.04 LTS (supported until 2021). Try them using Live USB first before installing, you might be hit by performance issues on a weak PC. That's why people suggest lighter alternatives like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I see some confusion here. Xubuntu and Lubuntu de facto are Ubuntu but with a different desktop environment. Given you're hardware you should download one of those 2.

Alternatively, download Ubuntu 16.04 and after you've installed it change desktop environment to Xfce4 (following this guide: [install Xfce on Ubuntu | itfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/install-xfce-desktop-xubuntu/)) or LXDE (following this guide: [install LXDE on Ubuntu | howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/)).